# fs.readdirSync(...).filter(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, glob

**Здравствуйте,прошу помочь**

**Вот код:**

```
fs.readdirSync(`${this.directory}Events`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js')).then(events => {         
            for (const eventFile of events) {
            delete require.cache[eventFile];
            const { name } = path.parse(eventFile);
            const File = require(eventFile);
            if (!this.isClass(File)) throw new TypeError(`Ивент ${name} не экспортирует класс.!`);
            const event = new File(this.Main, name);
            if (!(event instanceof Event)) throw new TypeError(`Ивент ${name} не принадлежит Ивентам`);
            this.Main.events.set(event.name, event);
            event.emitter[event.type](name, (...args) => event.run(...args));
        }})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then()` — это метод Promise. `fs.readdirSync()` — синхронная функция, она возвращает не Promise, а массив, то же самое делает `.filter()`. Присвойте значение этих синхронных вызовов переменной и дальше работайте с ней:

```
const events = fs.readdirSync(`${this.directory}Events`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const eventFile of events) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Теперь пишет Cannot find module 'guildCreate.js'

Comment: Хотя он есть,с командами работает

Comment: Это уже совсем другая проблема. Видимо, ошибка в строке `require(eventFile)` —  вы подаёте туда имя файла, а нужно абсолютный или относительный путь, дополните недостающее.

Comment: `fs.readdirSync()` возвращает имена файлов без директорий.

Comment: Спасибо,сделал глупую ошибку,я также делал как вы написали выше и получил тогда такую же ошибку,спасибо что показали мне мою маленькую ошибочку  :)